# Grails Mongodb plugin installation problem

Tags: grails-plugin, grails

While trying to install Mongodb grails plug in for grails application, i am getting following error

```
    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    :: org.springframework#spring-datastore-web;1.0.0.M3: not found

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Any clues what I am doing wrong....
Grails version is 1.3.6
Springsource Tool  2.3.3.CI-R5549-B45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add the relevant repository to the list that Grails searches to resolve dependencies. Looks like `spring-datastore-web` is in this SpringSource repos, so add the `mavenRepo` line below to the `repositories` section of your `/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy` file:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
  // ...
  repositories {
    // ...
    mavenRepo "http://s3browse.springsource.com/browse/maven.springframework.org/milestone/"
  }
 // ...
}
```

Hopefully the dependency will now be resolved and you can build the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the jar at https://github.com/grails/inconsequential and http://shrub.appspot.com/maven.springframework.org/snapshot/org/springframework/spring-datastore-web/1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/ rename it to "spring-datastore-web-1.0.0.M3.jar" than placed in lib .....